# Like keyword issue in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to display a result of `ADSTech` with the help of like Statement using `ADS Technology` keyword in MySQL like this

```
SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE `name` LIKE '%ADS Technology%'
```

This result is required

[image]

Also see my database screenshot

[image]

Comment: which is your server side language ?

Comment: OK. then see my answer will help you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not search because it's considering space.

you need to either remove space from keyword using before passing in query

```
$string_without_whitespaces = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

OR

```
$string_without_whitespaces = preg_replace('~\s~', '', $string);
```

OR split your keyword from space, like if using PHP use `explode()` and run your query around this array as per your needs.

```
$key=explode("",$keyword);
```

then

```
$query="SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$key[1]."%' OR '%".$key[2]."'";
```

OR

```
$query="SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$key[1].$key[2]."%'";
```

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience with me

Comment: hey @Teez this is a example keyword when i used this Query but my Q is if i search like this on my portal so which Query is the best result for this one more think those strings are not contain spaces what about them

Comment: You need to make query in loop according to that array.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question clearly, You can use any of the following query to get the results related to ADSTech or ADS Technology....

```
SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE `name` LIKE '%ADSTech%' OR `name` LIKE '%ADS Technology%';

SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE `name` IN ('ADSTech','ADS Technology');
```

Good Luck,

Comment: Your first query should be: `name LIKE '%ADSTech%' OR name LIKE '%ADS Technology%'`

Comment: how do i know my self a third person which strings are used for search

Answer (score 0):

You could have a table which stores aliases for companies and then use that in the like as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM subcategories sc, companyalias ca
WHERE ca.primaryname LIKE '%ADS Technology%'
  AND ca.name = sc.name
```

Comment: i m asking a simple Question why should i use this Query

Comment: This will be useful if you want to extend this to other cases as well. Otherwise, not useful.